# Is there a way to use a variable in a CountIf formula in order to iterate the column always by 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a attendance spreadsheet where we count the total Late and sick days using the CountIf function. Employees are listed one per column. I am trying to write a macro that will count the number of late or sick days per employee, enter that value to a cell and copy that value to a summary sheet. Then using a For Loop to iterate through each employee using the same range (number of rows) but always moving over one column.
This is my first time really using VBA so I am stuck as my code gives me an error when trying to iterate up the columns.
Thank you!

```
Sub Counting()
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-10]C[2]:RC[2],""L"")"
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Dim LastCol As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To LastCol

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-10]C[i]:RC[i],""L"")"

ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-10]C[i]:RC[i],""L"")"`

It looks like you want the value of i in here, not the letter "i", which you can do like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-10]C[" & i & "]:RC[" & i & "],""L"")"
```

This will fix your immediate error message, however the macro as whole is very fragile, you should read article PEH referenced and replace all those .Select / .Copy / .PasteSpecial as much as possible.

Alternatively, you can probably do what you need without a macro, and use formulas instead. If you can it would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks Edward. The only things is what that I want to be able to select any specific date in my worksheet (attendance is separated by date, so everyday is an entry) and be able to go back 365 days and do a count of all late and sick instances. So thats why I decided on doing a macro, so that I could select any date and perform those calculations. Which article are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to the article PEH mentioned in his comment above, to which you said "Thanks for the article".

Comment: Yeah I realized after I had send the response to you. Thank you.